# Can you use the sqlDataReader more than once?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question which I think I already know the answer to which is; can you use the sqlDataReader more than once?

I have a query which I run and the output of this is curently binding to a Repeater. I get the exepcted results and everything is working well. The challenge I now have is that I would like to use the same results, but instead of listing them in a Repeater, I want them loaded into a DropDownList. I've tried using the sqlDataReader twice 'in a row', but i'm guessing that once the Reader hits the end, there is nothing left to populate the DDL with?

Here is the code which does not work.

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CountryName From CountryList");
sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;
sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
if (sqlReader.HasRows)
{
    RepeaterCountries.DataSource = sqlReader;
        RepeaterCountries.DataBind();

        DDLCountry.DataSource = sqlReader;
        DDLCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        DDLCountry.DataValueField = "CountryName";
        DDLCountry.DataBind();
}
```

Is there a way that I can achieve this whereby I do not have to run another query against the database again? Any recommendations on if putting the results into an Array or something like that might work?

Comment: I think is better to create a List<string> and add CountryNames to that list and than use that where you need it.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll go ahead and use that method instead. I was curious as to if there was a way or not. TomTom has given a great explanation of what happens in this process which has satisfied my curiousity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not.

A data reader is a small wrapper around the TDS protocol and this is a forward only data set sent from the server.

The data reader does not keep a copy of the data, and sql server does not allow one to reset the data set (which is also does not remember), so you can not just move back in the data.

You either have to buffer internally, or you have to send the sql again.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation TomTom. This actually removes the curiousity factor I had about this on whether or not I could. So i'm glad that the answer was that I could not, and thus i used the other recommended method of putting the data into a List<String>

Comment: I would suggest you adding a link to the TDS so others can get familiar with that protocol, for example [TDS microsoft openspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/1ef08b76-1594-40cf-8ce0-d2407133dd3d)